# Matrix Equation of three matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I have square matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ each of dimension $n \times n$ in $\mathbb{M}_n({\mathbb{C}})$. These are related by the following equations:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
AB - BA &= iC\\
BC - CB &= iA\\
CA - AC &= iB\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $i = \sqrt{\left(-1\right)}$. Is it possible to obtain non trivial solution of such a system? Will the solution be unique? And does the dimension play a role here?

Comment: Where did you encounter these equations? In a physics exercise?

Comment: Yes, but I want to get a more mathematical treatment.

Comment: Then a book on Lie algebras is the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions. Clearly $A=B=C=0$ is always a solution. But, say, for $n=3$ we also have the matrices $A,B,C$ of the simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb C)$, given by
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i & 0\cr -i & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \;
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & i\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr -i & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \;
C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & -i\cr 0 & i & 0\end{pmatrix}. \;
$$
They satisfy the three equations. This can be generalised.

Comment: How do we exactly get these solutions? I can you give some references?

Thanks

Comment: We get this solution by knowing that the skew-symmetric matrices form a basis of this Lie algebra, and that there is a vector space basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ with exactly your Lie brackets, namely  $[e_1,e_2]=ie_3$ etc. The solution is not unique, however, because of replacing $i$ by $-i$ in the coefficients of $A$ and $B$. References are books on Lie algebras, or a book on physics (they always consider such Lie algebras).